# Opencv only binary image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Is there any class in opencv, which contains only binary image? My input images have only two value of pixels - black and white. Some functions change it and my output looks like this:

[image]

But I want to get only binary image in output.

Function I use:

```
cv::absidff
cv::bitwise_and, not, or, xor
cv::morphologyEx with random morphType and structuring element;
```

Is something which provide me that pixels cant be other than black or white?

Comment: There is no binary image type in OpenCV. `morphologyEx` could definitely cause what you're seeing.

Comment: un openCV binary means 0 = 0 and >0 = 1 ... if for you it is just for displaying you can always use binMat = grayMat>0;